# how to obtain JWT token in a api gateway architecture

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, api-gateway

Currently doing some research to setup an (azure) api gateway with oauth (jwt token) security.

an external partner/app sends a request to an api endpoint published on the gateway including a valid JWT-token in the header that gets validated by the gateway against AzureAD for example. When validated the request is routed to the backend service. No problems here.

My question is, what is best practice for the external app to obtain that JWT-token (to use for the api call) ?
Obviously, It could send a request to AzureAD with a clientid+secret to obtain a valid JWT token.  But to do so it has to call my internal AzureAD directly ? Is this the way to do it ?

or should I expose a 'get-jwt-token' api on my api gateway and route that request to AD ?  How should I secure that API ? with basic auth ?

or am I missing something, and is there a much better best/proven practice ?

Answer (score 0):

**HOSTING BEST PRACTICE**

A reverse proxy or API gateway is placed in front of both APIs and the Authorization Server (AS). This ensures that an attacker who somehow gains access to the back end entry point cannot access data sources.

**OAUTH REQUESTS TO GET TOKENS**

OAuth requests are typically proxied straight through the reverse proxy / API gateway to the AS with no extra logic. All credentials, auditing of login attempts etc remain in the AS.

**MANAGED SERVICES**

If using Azure AD as a cloud managed AS, this is a special case: the system is already hardened for internet clients, so most companies don't add their own proxying - though it is possible to do so.

**FURTHER INFO**

The first of these covers the infra setup and the second gives you an idea of extensibility options once a reverse proxy / gateway is in place.

- [IAM Primer](https://curity.io/resources/learn/iam-primer/)
- [API Gateway Guides](https://curity.io/resources/guides/apigateway/)